# Is an object a storage location or a value in C++?

Tags: c++, object, language-lawyer, storage, terminology

In C++, is an object a *storage location* (container) or a *value* (content)?

With this sentence from [[intro.object]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#intro.object-1), one can assume it is a value (bold emphasis mine):

> An object **occupies** a region of storage in its period of construction ([class.cdtor]), throughout its lifetime, and in its period of destruction ([class.cdtor]).

With this sentence from [[basic.types.general]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#types.general-2), one can assume it is a storage location (bold emphasis mine):

> For any object (other than a potentially-overlapping subobject) of trivially copyable type T, whether or not the object **holds** a valid value of type T, the underlying bytes ([intro.memory]) making up the object can be copied into an array of char, unsigned char, or std​::​byte ([cstddef.syn]).

Comment: An unitialized object occupies storage but does not hold a valid value.

Comment: a storage locations that holds a value maybe even if it is not initialized

Comment: An object is a value *and* the storage it occupies.

Comment: An object is an object.

Comment: An object is a region of storage and a set of operations that can be performed on that region of storage. Some objects have values because assigning and reading are valid operations on their storage.

Comment: @PeteBecker _An object is a region of storage_ Fortunately, this is no longer the case.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Could you elaborate?

Comment: @PeteBecker You are confusing objects with class objects. An `int` is an object yet it does not have methods.

Comment: @Maggyero `+` is an operation that can be performed on an `int` object. "a set of operations" != "member functions"

Comment: @Maggyero: Herb Sutter has even argued that the set of operations for **classes** is more than their members; it should also include the free functions defined in their header. Pete Becker has an entirely valid point.  In Comp.Sci terms, operations define the type, and the chief properties of an object are its type and position in memory.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues for a more thorough analysis.

Comment: @MSalters ‘chief properties of an object are its type and position in memory.’ Interesting. But non-objects such as references and functions also have a type, don’t they?

Comment: @Maggyero: True, and more importantly expressions such as `2+2` have type. Type is a property of objects, but it's not unique to objects.

Comment: @MSalters So isn’t the chief (distinguishing) property of an object its location (so object ≠ value)?

Comment: @Maggyero: It's very important, but that location may coincide with the location of a sub-object (member or base). You need both type and location.

Comment: @Maggyero -- I didn't (and don't) use the word "methods". Read what I said. An `int` object has operations that can be performed on it: you can store a value, read the stored value, increment the stored value, decrement the stored value, etc.

Comment: @MSalters ‘It's very important, but that location may coincide with the location of a sub-object (member or base). You need both type and location.’ I see, you mean that without specifying its type, a derived object would be confused with its base object, as [\[intro.object\]/6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#intro.object-6) specifies: ‘If a complete object, a member subobject, or an array element is of class type, its type is considered the most derived class, to distinguish it from the class type of any base class subobject;’

Comment: @PeteBecker My bad, I thought you were only referring to member functions. Now where does the standard specify that an object has a set of operations? It specifies that it has a type, at [\[intro.object\]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic#intro.object-1), so I am assuming that you derived that from there, but then where is a type specified that way?

Comment: @Maggyero -- that's a compiler writer's notion of an object. It offers a very helpful perspective.

Comment: @PeteBecker I like your clear definition (object = storage location + type). Didn’t you forget the *storage duration*, since different objects can have the same storage location at non-overlapping time periods (object = storage location + storage duration + type)?

Comment: @MSalters Do you agree with my last comment to PeteBecker?

Comment: @Maggyero: No. _Storage duration_ is a specific term in C++. I suspect you mean _lifetime_. Since you're trying to be hyper-precise here, the differences between those terms is huge. There are only a few possible storage durations. (auto, static, thread)

Comment: @MSalters Yes sorry, I meant *object lifetime*, which is just a subset of storage duration (duration of storage allocation). So I meant object = storage location + lifetime + type. Do you agree with this definition?

Comment: @Maggyero: Those are indeed the minimal properties. Some objects have more properties, e.g. a name. And note that since C++11, lifetimes are only restricted by _sequenced-after_ and _sequenced-before_ constraints.

Comment: @MSalters I see. Can objects change location during their lifetime in memory in C++ like objects in the real world, or they can only have a fixed location?

Comment: @Maggyero: According to the standard, no, but in real-life the as-if optimization rules kick in. Therefore, creating a pointer to an object can prevent optimizations

Comment: @MSalters Thanks. SergeBallesta made the interesting comment that move construction can be seen as a way to change an object’s location in memory (like we would move a cup of tea in real space). In this view, an object (besides its type) is no more a *single* fixed storage location and a lifetime, but a *sequence* of storage locations at different times.

Comment: @Maggyero: Well, that's just conceptual. C++ makes it very explicit : moving involves calling the "move constructor", which like all constructors creates a new object in a new location. Afterwards, typically the destructor is called on the moved-from object, but this can be quite a bit later. In the mean time, two objects exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An **object** is an *entity* that has a **type** (a set of operations that can be performed on it) and occupies some allocated **storage region** with the proper *size* (given by the operator `sizeof`) and *alignment* (given by the operator `alignof`) for the type. The storage region has an *address* (given by the operator `&`) and holds a *representation* which is a sequence of bytes, a subset of which represents a *value*. An object finally has a **lifetime** which starts at the end of its initialization, and ends at the start of its finalization or when its storage region is deallocated or reused by another object.

Using an object outside its lifetime is undefined behaviour.

As a programmer can change the representation of an object at any time by directly accessing its bytes, an object can hold a valid value or not. Invalid values for basic types are known as *trap representation* and using an object containing such a trap representation is undefined behaviour.

So an object is neither a storage region nor a value, but a complex thing that is called object in C language.

Comment: Thanks. All the properties that you give seem to apply to a storage location (has address and therefore has value, has type, and has size), except the lifetime property which bounds the time extent of the storage location. So do you agree that an object is a storage location *at a given period* (i.e. a spatio-*temporal* extent)?

Comment: You are forgotting about the type... An object has a type and accessing it with an incorrect type (except for the character types) is explicitely UB.

Comment: Okay, so object = storage location + storage duration + type?

Comment: @Maggyero: I cannot think of other key attributes. So yes, it is all that.

Comment: Sorry, I meant object = storage location + lifetime + type. Can objects change location during their lifetime in memory in C++ like objects in the real world, or they can only have a fixed location?

Comment: @Maggyero: The address of an object cannot change. But an object can be *moved* in which case you will get a strictly equivalent object in a different location. But the move will end the lifetime of the original object and create a new (even if not really independant) one.

Comment: That is a very interesting insight, I hadn’t thought about seeing move construction as a way to change an object’s location in memory, like we would move a cup of tea in real space. In this view, an object (besides its type) is no more a *single* fixed storage location and a lifetime, but a *sequence* of storage locations at different times.

Comment: _An object is an entity_ Inclusion of objects into [entities](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/basic.pre#def:entity) is likely a defect.